# Archive template combined with post slider and regular posts

Tags: posts, query-posts, paged, archive-template

I am trying to find the best and easiest way of modifying my **archive.php** template to contain slider on top which slides the 4 first posts and the rest (6) will be displayed beneath as a regular posts.

it should work dynamically with one loop, meaning that if I am clicking on "Previous" or "next" posts and get the paged archive it should work normally and display the same structure starting with the 4 first (in that paged archive) in the slider continuing beneath it with 6 regular posts.

Also I need the name of the category on top but not including other categories which share the same posts!

It seems like a pretty simple Query. the only thing I am concerned bout is how to loop through the slider which contains 2 part: the 4 slider boxes on the right and the faded images on the left.

to better understand what I am trying to achieve here. here is an image I prepared to explain it:

[image]

would appreciate any help
Thanks. Gil

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of doing this. You could, for instance, incorporate a counter into your loop and treat the post data with respect to the counter's value.

```
YOUR QUERY HERE
$my_counter = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$my_counter++;
if ( $my_counter <= 4 ) {
    SLIDER ACTION
} else {
    REGULAR POST ACTION
}
endwhile;
```

Comment: Anyway you can add the loop examples (Slider action and Regular posts action) to that code? I am not such an experienced developer. Thanks!

Comment: WPSE is not a *work for me for free* site. Your question is over-broad, but this answer covers the main part of the question: how to output the first four posts separately as a slider, followed by the remaining 6 posts.

Comment: I dont intend to use this site as a "work for me for free" as you mentioned. just wanted to have a small example no the whole code. for instance - how do I treat the slider? it has 2 <ul> lists which need to loop: The slider pictures and the text links that change the slider photos. what do I do in that case? any rough example?